# linear functional definition

Tags: linear-transformations

I am unable to understand
what is meant by 'unique'  in the theorem on linear functionals given in Axler's  Linear Algebra Done Right, edition 3.

Theorem 6.45 Suppose $\phi$ is a linear functional on vector space $V$. Then there is a unique vector $v$ in $V$ such that
$\phi(u)= \langle u,v\rangle$ for every $u$ in $V$.

Does it mean  a fixed vector $v$ or a special ( unique)  vector $v$ ?
Taking functional as  product of a row vector $(v)$ and a column vector $(u)$  of same dimension , one can take any fixed $v$ and get a scalar that is linear with respect to $u$. Is it correct ?

Answer (score 0):

For a given functional $\phi$, there is only one such vector $v$.  Another way of putting it is that all linear functionals are of the form $$\phi(u_1,u_2,\dots,u_n)=v_1u_1+v_2u_2+\cdots+v_nu_n$$ for some constants $v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n.$  Then $v=(v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n).$